# SharePoint mixing list schema

Tags: list, feature, solution-deployment, custom-schema

I've a solution for SharePoint 2013 where I created several list and added them to a feature. When I deploy the solution to my dev environment every list has the same schema (the same columns).

They are all custom lists, made by me.

What am I missing?

**More details**

For example, I created a list called "List1" with the columns Title and Image. Deployed it to SharePoint 2013 and it worked fine.

Then I created a list called "List2" with the columns Title, Description and Status. Deployed everything again and saw that "List2" have the same columns as "List1" (Title and Image). Looks like SharePoint is using the same schema.xml for both lists.

Also, the lists are deployed in a feature called "Lists".

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Solution Explorer window in Visual Studio showing your custom lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem changing the template property in the list instance element.xml and in the list element.xml, as shown in the pictures below:

**The files**

[image: print-1]

In the list instance Element.xml I changed the TemplateType from 100 (general list type) to 1000 (a number that doesn't represent any default SharePoint template type).

[image: print-2]

In the list Element.xml I also changed the Type from 100 to 1000.

[image]

For every new list I incremented that number, like 1001, 1002, 1003 and so on. Now SharePoint doesn't mix the lists schemas.